# No build() and create() vs build() vs create() in Factory Boy

Tags: python, django, pytest-django, factory-boy, pytest-factoryboy

I created `UserFactory` class in `factories.py` as shown below. I use [pytest-django](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-django) and [pytest-factoryboy](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-factoryboy) in Django:

```py
# "factories.py"

import factory

from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = User

    username = "John"
```

Then, I registered `UserFactory` class in `conftest.py` as shown below:

```py
# "conftest.py"

import pytest

from pytest_factoryboy import register
from tests.factories import UserFactory

register(UserFactory)
```

Then, I created `test_user()` which prints `username` with `user_factory` and [user_factory.build()](https://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference.html#factory.Factory.build) and [user_factory.create()](https://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference.html#factory.Factory.create) in `test_ex1.py` as shown below:

```py
# "test_ex1.py"

import pytest

from django.contrib.auth.models import User

def test_user(db, user_factory):
    print(user_factory.username) # Here
    print(user_factory.build().username) # Here
    print(user_factory.create().username) # Here
    assert True
```

Then, I got 3 `John`'s as shown below:

```
$ pytest -q -rP
.                                [100%]
=============== PASSES ================
____________ test_new_user ____________
-------- Captured stdout call ---------
John
John
John
1 passed in 0.55s
```

My questions:

1. What is the difference between `user_factory`, `user_factory.build()` and `user_factory.create()` in Factory Boy?
2. When should I use `user_factory`, `user_factory.build()` and `user_factory.create()` in Factory Boy?

Answer (score 1):

> - `build` provides a local object
> - `create` instantiates a local object, and saves it to the database.

https://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/introduction.html#strategies

Your 'second John' has not been saved to the database while the third one has.